# Column separator extend above text

Tags: columns, dimensions, paracol

I am working on a bilingual document with parallel text, occasionally interupted by monolingual sections (i.e. spanning the whole page width) in between. Each time the parallel text begins, the line I have dividing the columns extends above the top of the text, but is perfectly flush with the bottom. Is there a way I can get the line flush on both ends? The only thing I have figured out to try is to eliminate the space above the paragraph, but this apparently was not the problem. Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    Accipio.
    \switchcolumn
    I do accept it.
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is at the top of the line box If you replaced  `I` by `Î` your line would not be protuding at the top, if you deleted the `p` it would be protuding at the bottom as it would still leave space for a descender

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I was aware of it extending with the descender (which is actually desirable in my application), but it only does this when there IS a descender. Since there are no diacritics above the capital here (or anywhere in this document), is there a way to bring the line down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first baseline is controlled by `\topskip`

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{paracol}

\setlength\textwidth{6cm}%just  for demo
\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength\topskip{7pt}
    \begin{paracol}{2}
    Accipio.
    \switchcolumn
    I do accept it.
    \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked excellently in my MWE, thank you! It does nothing in my actual document, however. Could one of these be interfering?
`\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
[dvipsnames]{xcolor}{ragged2e} {blindtext}[autocompile]{gregoriotex}{multicol}{fontspec}{lettrine}{lmodern}{paracol}{setspace}{anyfontsize}{microtype}{bbding}{graphicx}{stackengine}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setmainfont{garamond-libre}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}`

Comment: you have multicol and paracol at same time?anyway feel free to post a new question with a new example you can reference this one. Without an example I can't really say.

Comment: I had switched from multicol to paracol, and clearly forgot to remove the former, thank you! I will try to come up with a MWE where the fix does not work, and repost. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: I did as you suggested: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671429/column-separator-extends-above-text-if-the-column-is-not-the-first-item-in-the-d